# Why does my android app read åäö but my java app doesn't(when getting data from GAE)?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, servlets, utf-8

I'm using Google App Engine to fetch some data. Before sending the data from GAE, I set the content type to "text/html" and the character encoding to "UTF-8". I'm certain that the characters åöä are stored correctly on the server database.

When getting the data from my android app, everything works fine. The characters åäö are represented correctly. Here's the strange part: when getting the same data from my java app on windows, åäö gets replaced by "Ã¥" and other strange symbols. When getting the same data from my java app on a mac, åäö gets replaced by some other strange characters.

So my question is: Why does the android app read the string correctly while the java app doesn't?

EDIT:

Here's how I send the string from GAE:

```
resp.setContentType("text/html");
resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
resp.getWriter().println(myString);
```

Here's how I read it in java both on android and windows:

```
String response = "";
try {
URL url = new URL("http://mydomain.com/blabla");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
   response += line;
}
wr.close();
rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Response is: " + response);
```

Comment: paste that code which produces and reads the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know the data is wrong on Windows and the Mac? Are you printing it out to, say, a console? If so, it's likely (especially on Windows) that the console character encoding is wrong. You'll be writing UTF-8 encoded characters to the console which will be trying to interpret them as Windows CP-whatever.

Comment: Yes I'm printing it out to both a console and a GUI. How do I prevent the console from trying to interpret them as Windows CP-whatever?

Comment: @Emiam Print out the unicode codepoints, or print out the bytes in hex, and compare them on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you do not explicitly say that the UTF-8 encoding should be used for decoding strings, and that it is done by the default platform encoding.

Comment: Ah yes. For some reason I misread "text/html" as "text/html; charset=utf-8" and assumed the relevant HTTP library would have taken care of the encoding. But you're right, this is definitely a possibility.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Do you mean that I'm not setting the proper settings on the GAE server? Please view my updated question above.